# Vertica comparison operator with timestamp

Tags: database, vertica

I have billion records in Vertica table with times_tamp in timestamptz datatype. I want to delete records older than 90 Days in one statement. how do I do this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best practice is to explicitly define the date as part of your query:

```
DELETE FROM [schema].table WHERE times_stamp <= '2014-05-06';
```

However, you can accomplish this dynamically using:

```
DELETE FROM [schema].table WHERE DATEDIFF(day, times_stamp, SYSDATE()) >= 90;
```

This will remove rows that have a day difference greater than or equal to 90.

I would recommend doing a `SELECT` with that predicate prior to removing these rows to verify the rows being deleted, as well as using a transaction.

Consider using partitions in the future as there is a high cost of deleting rows (containers will need to be reorganized). If you partition on month for example, you will be able to immediately remove those containers.

Comment: We have this data partitioned by week. we will be holding 90 days of data in it. Is that good way ?

Comment: Estimating about 13 weeks of data, do you pump and dump the data? It's not clear whether you have a moving window or after the end of 90 days you just dump the entire table.

Comment: Yes, we do add new data every hours and delete data older than 90 days

Comment: That's a resource intensive process. I would only remove data once a week, on a partition.

Comment: I think thats good thought, removing data over the weekend when there is less/no load.

Comment: @user3579198 Yep. Read over [this documentation](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.0.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/AdministratorsGuide/Partitions/DroppingPartitions.htm) on how to remove the entire week's partition.

Comment: Removing data over the week end: if you drop partitions, this is an almost instant and free process without much resource needed. Dropping partition once a week is by far the best option.

Comment: On a side node, if you go the DELETE route, you will end up having a lot of delete vectors, which if you do not PURGE your table will have a very bad performance impact (we had orders of magnitude of slowdown).

Comment: Small comment on the second SELECT: as it applies a function on all row sof your column, it will be *very* slow as Vertica will not be able to optimise it, and will have to process each row individually. A better option is to move the calculation to the other side of the '=', which will then be computed only once for the whole query: DELETE FROM [schema].table WHERE time_stamp <= NOW() - INTERVAL '90 day'. But see my previous comment, you will have issues with delete vectors if you use it as is.

Comment: @Guillaume regarding the function in the predicate, I'd be very curious if Vertica actually does this type of optimization.

Comment: @Kermit As long as the field is isolated with no wrapped function or expression and the other side is a literal or expression that returns a literal, the potential is there for Vertica to optimize (very likely based on the ROS min/max, then if sorted possibly further).